# contentful graphql fetch a link to the image from a content's media field

Tags: graphql, gatsby, contentful

When using **Contentful** with Gatsby, how do I retrieve an image from a content's media field via Gatsby's GraphQL?
(like a link to the image would do)

Let's say I have a content model called "**Article**", that contains below 3 fields:

| field name | field type |
| --- | --- |
| title | Short text |
| description | Short text |
| photo | Media |

I write a content with an image attached to "photo".

When I go to GraphQL and I can find "title" and "description" under `allArticle.edges.node`., but not "photo".

How do I retrieve media referenced in a content from GraphQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three options:

- Your changes are not published: so publish them.
- You have the previous cache: run `gatsby clean` and try it again
- You haven't added any image: so add it (publish your changes)

Once your image is displayed and the node is created, use a GraphQL fragment to get it or the bunch of parameters needed (contained in the fragment):

```
{
  allArticle {
    edges {
      node {
        title
        description
        photo {
          fixed(width: 1600) {
            width
            height
            src
            srcSet
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: running `gatsby clean` solved the issue. I was able to see the url from the query. also `photo.file.url` seems to return the url to the asset!